# grouping and summing up dummy vars from caret R

Tags: r, r-caret

I have data like this

```
dataset = data.frame(id = c(1,2,1,4,5,6), class = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b') )
```

I want to convert it into dummy vars but caret's dummy vars doesn't collapse id up it returns the same number of rows as the input. How do I group it so that id 1 has both a and b variables as 1?

```
dummies <- caret::dummyvars(id ~ . , data=dataset)
predict(dummies, newdata = dataset)
```

Comment: What's your intended output?

Answer (score 0):

In this case use dcast function for data.table:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dataset)

dataset[,dummy:=1]    
d2 = dcast(dataset,id~class,value.var = 'dummy',fun.aggregate = length)
d2[is.na(d2)] = 0
```

Note that this solution will return the number of a's and b's found for each id. If you need only 1 or 0 change for example the fun.aggregate to be

```
fun.aggregate = function(x) as.integer(length(x) >0)
```

---

dummyVars works row wise and for that it doesn't matter what is the value in `id`

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate your predicted variable. So if you store the outcome of predict in the variable named dummies2:

```
aggregate(. ~ id, data=dummies2, FUN=sum)
```